# Vue router not routing with URL paths

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-component, webpack-dev-server, vue-router4

So I'm working with Vue 3 and Vue Router 4 and I'm having an issue when running my code with webpack-dev-server. Whenever I run my app `webpack-dev-server --mode development` the landing page looks great and loads everything from my `App.vue` file. However, whenever I change the route from the base route `/` to my new component `/test` it just loads the same exact view as the base route. I've been browsing for hours and can't seem to figure out what's wrong when I'm sure it's a simple fix. Here's the current structure of my directory:

- src

  - components

    - Homepage.vue
  - router

    - index.js
- App.vue
- index.html
- main.js
- package.json
- webpack.config.js

here is what's inside some of those important files

`src/router/index.js`

```js
import Vue from 'vue'
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

import App from '../App.vue'
import Homepage from '../components/Homepage.vue'

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: App },
  { path: '/test', component: Homepage }
]

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes: routes
})

export default router
```

`src/main.js`

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';

createApp(App)
  .use(router)
  .mount('#app');
```

`package.json`

```js
{
  "name": "web",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js",
    "serve": "webpack-dev-server --mode development",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.2.5",
    "bootstrap": "^5.2.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "vue": "^3.2.39",
    "vue-router": "^4.0.13"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.19.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.19.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "vue-loader": "^17.0.0",
    "vue-style-loader": "^4.1.3",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10",
    "webpack": "^5.74.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "^5.8.0"
  }
}
```

`webpack.config.js`

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
// const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin');
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    publicPath: "/"
  },
  devServer: {
    static: {
      directory: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    },
    allowedHosts: 'all',
    compress: true,
    https: true,
    historyApiFallback: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
      { test: /\.vue$/, use: 'vue-loader' },
      { test: /\.css$/, use: ['vue-style-loader', 'css-loader']},
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
    }),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
  ]
};
```

I tried modifying my routes, installing new packages/libraries, messing with my webpack config file, copying over loads of code from online, but alas, nothing worked.

Comment: Any reason you're manually controlling Webpack instead of using the vue-cli-service? Why not use the [official Vue starter via Vite](https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application)?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to show the relevant parts of `index.html`. Where are you using `<router-view>`?